# Having trouble creating a python linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

This is the code I'm working with right now, I'm trying to complete the insertNode(list, index, value) function (a general insert function that will insert a node into an empty list [@head of a list/tail/middle]).

The insertNode() function is supposed to use the "index" parameter to indicate where in the list to insert the new node and should return the head of the modified list.

I've been working on this for days and I'm not sure if its the syntax or my understanding, the code just does not seem to work. Please help.

Also, if I want to use the return value from nthNode (eg. ptr) for another function, is it correct to make it a global value?

```
global ptr

def createList(plist):
    """
    Creates and returns a linked list containing all of the elements
    of the Python-style list parameter.  A useful shortcut for testing.
    """
    linkedList = None
    # goes backwards, adding each element to the beginning
    # of the list.  
    for index in range(len(plist)-1, -1, -1):
        linkedList = insertValueHead(linkedList, plist[index])
    return linkedList


def emptyList():
  #creates an empty linked list
  return None   #absence of a value -- nothing


def insertValueHead(linkedList, value):
    #linkedList is the head of the list to be added to
    #value is the data to be stored in the node
    #inserts a new value at the head of the linked list
    newnode = {}
    newnode["data"] = value
    #set the next pointer of this new node to the head of the list, linkedList
    #newnode is now the head of the list 
    newnode["next"] = linkedList
    return newnode


def nthNode(linkedList, n):
    """
    Helper method: returns a reference to node n in a list
    (counting from zero).
    Parameters: the list and an index n
    If there is no node n, returns None.
    """

    ptr = linkedList
    count = 0
    if n < 0:
        return None

    while ptr != None and count < n:
        ptr = ptr['next']
        count += 1
    return ptr


def insertNode(myList,index,value):

  #This function is a general function for inserting values in a linked list.  I have provided a
  #skeleton, it is your job to complete it.

  #case 1:  Adding to the head of the list -- index == 0
  #Create a new node and pass back the new node, which is the new head of the list.

    if index==0:
        value['next']=linkedList
        linkedList=value
        return linkedList



  #case 2:  Adding elsewhere in the list
  #use nthNode() to find the node before the position to insert (this will be at index - 1)
  #if this function returns None, then the index is invalid -- print an error message
  #otherwise, add the node


    else:
        if nthNode(linkedList,n)==None:
            print 'Index is invalid'
        else:
            ptr=nthNode(linkedList,n)
            value['next']=ptr['next']
            ptr['next']=value 
            return linkedList



def switch(list, index):
  #Add your code here.
  pass  #remove this once you add code

def removeEvens(list):
  #Add your code here
  pass #remove this once you add code



def listString(linkedList):
  #creates a string representation of the values in the linked list
  ptr = linkedList
  str1 = "["
  while ptr != None:
    str1 += str(ptr['data'])
    ptr = ptr['next']
    if ptr != None:
      str1 += ","
  str1 = str1 + "]"
  return str1

def printList(linkedList):
  #prints all the values in the linked list
  print "in printList"
  return listString(linkedList)


def testInsert():
  #test code to ensure that insertNode is working correctly.
  myList = createList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
  print "The initial list", printList(myList)
  #insert 0 at the head
  myList = insertNode(myList,0, 0)
  print "Inserted 0 at the start of list: ", printList(myList)
  #insert 7 at the end
  myList = insertNode(myList, 7, 7)
  print "Inserted 7 at the end of list: ", printList(myList)
  myList= insertNode(myList, 3, 2.2)
  print "Inserted 2.2 in the 3rd position ", printList(myList)
  myList = insertNode(myList, 26, 12)   #should generate an error

def testSwitch():
    #test code to ensure that switch() is working correctly.
    myList = createList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    print "The initial list", printList(myList)
    myList = switch(myList, 0)
    print "Switching the 1 and the 2.  Resulting list is ", printList(myList)
    myList = switch(myList, 3)
    print "Switching the 4 and the 5.  Resuling list is ", printList(myList)
    myList = switch(myList, 5)  #should result in an error
    myList = switch(myList, 29)  #should result in an error

def testRemoveEvens():
    #test code to ensure that removeEvens() is working correctly.
    myList= createList([1, 7, 4, 15, 16, 22])
    print "The initial list", printList(myList)
    myList = removeEvens(myList)
    print "With evens removed, list is :", printList(myList)
    myList = createList([2, 7, 4, 15, 16, 3])
    print "The initial list", printList(myList)
    myList = removeEvens(myList)
    print "With evens removed, list is :", printList(myList)


def main():
    #create an empty list
    #linkedList is the head of the list
    linkedList = emptyList()
    print "Inserting a new node with value 9"
    linkedList = insertValueHead(linkedList, 9)
    printList(linkedList)
    print "Inserting a new node with value 20"
    linkedList = insertValueHead(linkedList, 20)
    printList(linkedList)

main()
```

Comment: `Also, if I want to use the return value from nthNode (eg. ptr) for another function, is it correct to make it a global value?` - almost certainly no.

Comment: Thank you for replying, is it correct to assign a variable to the function I want the return value of inside the other function then? (ptr=nthNode(linkedList,n))?